# Selecting records using year and month fields - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select records from a table using a range of a given year and month I'm using this SQL Server sentence which works fine if I use different years as starting year but if I use the same year and different month does not work.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Clave Titular Cedula]
      ,[Clave Cifcod]
      ,[Clave Anio corte historico]
      ,[Clave Mes de corte historico]
      ,[Clave Tipo de tarjeta]
      ,[ClaveCodigo grupo inf#promocio]
      ,[Clave Codigo subgrupo inf#prom#]
      ,[Cant# Compras]
      ,[Valor Compras]
  FROM [Prueba].[dbo].[Gasto]
     where ([Clave Titular Cedula] = '0917947160' and [Clave Cifcod] = '284849' and [ClaveCodigo grupo inf#promocio] = '05')
and  (([Clave Anio corte historico] = '2016' and [Clave Mes de corte historico] >= 02)
     or ([Clave Anio corte historico]  > '2016' and [Clave Anio corte historico] < '2016')
     or ([Clave Anio corte historico] = '2016' and [Clave Mes de corte historico] <= 09) )
```

For example this returns event the records from month 01 instead from month 02 as starting month.

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Borys

Comment: Your last or statement allows all months less than 10 in 2016 to be returned - and month 1 is part of that.  You need to refactor your query.  If you're looking for a RANGE - try to use between for the months

Comment: Not for nothing but `([Clave Anio corte historico]  > '2016' and [Clave Anio corte historico] < '2016')`  - what's the point of this in your query?  no record can meet both those criteria - set Clave Anio Corte Historice = 2016 and Clave Mes de corte historico BETWEEN 2 AND 9

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, by excluding all wrong options. I prefer that you combine the year and month like:yyyy-mm

```
SELECT * FROM tables WHERE NOT (From_date < #RangeEnd OR To_date > #RangeStart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query simplified is:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [Clave Titular Cedula]
    ,[Clave Cifcod]
    ,[Clave Anio corte historico]
    ,[Clave Mes de corte historico]
    ,[Clave Tipo de tarjeta]
    ,[ClaveCodigo grupo inf#promocio]
    ,[Clave Codigo subgrupo inf#prom#]
    ,[Cant# Compras]
    ,[Valor Compras]
FROM 
    [Prueba].[dbo].[Gasto]
where 
    ( [Clave Titular Cedula] = '0917947160' )
    and ( [Clave Cifcod] = '284849' )
    and ( [ClaveCodigo grupo inf#promocio] = '05')
    and ( [Clave Anio corte historico] = '2016' ) 
    and ( [Clave Mes de corte historico] between 02 and 09 )
```